Accumulo/GeoMesa GeoTools API Iterator
Is there a way to call an Accumulo(https://github.com/apache/accumulo/tree/2.1/core/src/main/java/org/apache/accumulo/core/iterators) or GeoMesa (https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/tree/main/geomesa-accumulo/geomesa-accumulo-iterators/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/accumulo/iterators) iterator using GeoTools API?
I want to create a custom iterator that I can call from the Java client using GeoTools API to query to GeoMesa.

does this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78481064/439194) help?

@Ian Turton This question was asked by me but I have a different question about the API.

Then you will probably need to show some code, to show us where you have got to.

@Ian Turton I want to know if GeoTools API has a way to query to GeoMesa by passing an iterator. This question is not related to programming just wanting to obtain proof that this is possible.

The GeoTools API does not know about Accumulo iterators.
In order to query Accumulo using GeoTools, one would need to write a GeoTools DataStore interface.  GeoMesa has implemented the GeoTools DataStore interfaces.
This tutorial explains the various interfaces involved in doing so: https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/datastore/index.html
(For context, I referred to those tutorials will implementing various parts of GeoMesa.)
In order to use a custom iterator in GeoMesa, you will need to modify the internals of GeoMesa and make a custom version of GeoMesa.  Depending on your use case, perhaps it would be easier to contribute your changes to GeoMesa.

Appreciate your comment. Instead of implementing changes in GeoMesa, am I able to create an Accumulo custom iterator and set it at scan time? Does using GeoTools API scan the accumulo db? If so, then the custom iterator would likely get executed. This is the method that I tried however a simple custom iterator is not running so that makes me think the GeoTools API doesn't trigger execution of the iterator.

GeoMesa implements the GeoTools API.  The GeoTools API does not directly know anything about Accumulo.  GeoTools parses CQL into Java objects and then GeoMesa turns that into a plan for how to scan Accumulo.
If you managed to configure Accumulo to run your iterator, it would have to know how to read the Kryo serialized bytes that GeoMesa has written.  That would be pretty hard to do without understanding how GeoMesa works.
Your best bet would be to express your query as CQL and just use GeoMesa.  If that cannot be done, you should look at extending GeoMesa's existing iterators.

Thanks for replying, if I create a class and extend an existing GeoMesa iterator which are in scala, would I be able to pass a parameter to that custom GeoMesa iterator via GeoTools API?
